# How to escape mouse selection in Terminal.App

Tags: terminal, mouse

I am using a mouse enabled application in the terminal but now I want to copy some text. By this I mean, I want to select text in the terminal with the mouse and copy it with Command+C to copy it to a different program.
However, selecting does not work because the application captures the mouse and does other things. So, e.g. dragging in vim will select text in vim but then Command+C does not work for copying.

On other systems this can often be fixed by holding shift. Is there a similar thing for Terminal.App?

Comment: It might help to know what the application is? Have you asked their support channels about this issue?

Comment: It applies to all applications, e.g. vim and tmux.

Comment: *"I am using a mouse enabled application in the terminal"* … which application?

Comment: The ones I previously gave as an example: vim and tmux.

Comment: Have to see if someone else has any ideas. I really don't know what you're asking. You're talking about some 'application' that enables the mouse in Terminal… but you're not explaining what it is. I'm not even sure what you mean by enabling the mouse. It's already enabled.

Comment: If you are using the OS-shipped vim, then a mouse click should move the cursor, and a click and drag should put the editor in visual mode and do a select.  What *does* occur?  You're asking someone to provide you a fix for a problem you're not describing.

Comment: Oh, now I maybe understand what your problem is. I edited the question a bit.

Comment: @Tetsujin "The application" could be vim. For example, Vim with "set mouse=a" "captures" the mouse events. Meaning using the mouse now does things in vim. So if I want to select text in the terminal it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: `set mouse=` , copy your text, `set mouse=a` again.

Comment: @MarcWilson Technically works but then I also have to do the same for tmux and everything else and it gets pretty inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a hint in a different question that Command+R turns off mouse support. It's actually [documented](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/keyboard-shortcuts-trmlshtcts/mac) if you know what to look for.

So, Cmd+R, copy&paste, Cmd+R seems to work.

Sidenote: In iTerm2 it's Option+T.